# jQuery addClass method not working in FF 34.0.5

Tags: jquery, class, firefox, addclass

I have some code like this:

```
$(document).on("taphold", ".card-cart", function(event) {
     if ($(this).hasClass("delete-mode-on")) {
         $(this).toggleClass("delete-mode-on");
         $(this).find(".card-delete-area").addClass("hidden");
     }
     else {
         $(this).siblings(".card-cart").removeClass("delete-mode-on").find(".card-delete-area").addClass("hidden");
         $(this).toggleClass("delete-mode-on");
         $(this).find(".card-delete-area").removeClass("hidden"); 
     }
 });
```

When I test the code in FF it's not adding the class, but it works find in Safari, IE 11 and Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any error on the console? don't think sunch an important method as `addClass` is not working on latest browser versions.

Comment: I had the same issue with ff 34 and addClass

Comment: Is the handler running at all?

Comment: Does this simple fiddle work in FF: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly5dpbho/1/)? If it does, then you should try to create a simple jsfiddle that reproduces the behavior so that we can test against that.

Comment: Seems fine in FF34.0.5: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly5dpbho/2

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional debugging I determined that some corruptly parsed JSON was saved in my `<div>` as HTML 5 data tags created by a `for` loop.  I removed the corrupted data and that resolved the issue.`

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
$(selector).hide();
```

are you sure, that your selector is selecting the right node?
maybe try your selector with

```
$(yourselector).css({border: '1px solid red'});
```

and see if it works

Comment: The thing is... straight CSS does work.. only add class WITH the css doesn't, not does the class show as being added in Firebug.